# yAxis tickinterval in highcharts is not working as per the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Currently i am working on radar chart in highcharts. so when providing the `tickInterval` value in `yAxis` is not plotting as per the given value. I mentioned the bug exactly in commenting. please refer it. and here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0hdfq31/1/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            polar: true
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
        },
        pane: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360
        },
        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 45,
            min: 0,
            max: 360,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '°';
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
        //providing tickInterval '1' is not working
        //but providing tickInterval '2' is working
            tickInterval: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: 0,
                pointInterval: 45
            },
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Column',
            data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
            pointPlacement: 'between'
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: 'Line',
            data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Area',
            data: [1, 8, 2, 7, 3, 6, 4, 5]
        }]
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So, That's a good question and what the highcharts doing in `tickInterval` is its calculating the tickInterval based on the user given value and it rounds values to make more readable.

But, the solution to your problem can be solved using [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner).
You can give your own axis value like this :

```
yAxis: {
   tickPositions: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
}
```

Here is the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/nx9xuLo4/)

and you can also write a custom function for your tickPositioner like this

```
var ticks = [];
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    ticks.push(i+1);
    }

yAxis: {
  tickPositions: ticks
}
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/nx9xuLo4/1/)

Comment: Thanks it is working. see this updated fiddle using your answer. http://jsfiddle.net/nx9xuLo4/2/.